# Trying to make a virtual keypad in Bootstrap using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

There's a simple textbox with a virtual keypad that toggles in and out as the user clicks the keyboard icon inside of the text box:

[image]

each letter is a clickable button and the idea is to populate the text box with the value of the button being clicked. Here's what I've done:

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <input id="word" type="textbox" placeholder="Enter your word here..." class="form-control input-lg">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="toggler('virtualkeypad');"><span class="fa fa-keyboard-o fa-2x lookup-icon"></span></a>
    <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button" id="lookup">Lookup</button></span>
</div>

<div id="virtualkeypad" class="col-md-offset-4 hidden">
    <button id="key" class="btn btn-lg special-char-btn first-btn" type="button">á</button>
    <button id="key" class="btn btn-lg special-char-btn" type="button">é</button>
    <button id="key" class="btn btn-lg special-char-btn" type="button">í</button>
    <button id="key" class="btn btn-lg special-char-btn" type="button">ó</button>
    <button id="key" class="btn btn-lg special-char-btn" type="button">ú</button>
    <button id="key" class="btn btn-lg special-char-btn" type="button">ü</button>
    <button id="key" class="btn btn-lg special-char-btn last-btn" type="button">ñ</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function toggler(divId) {
    $("#" + divId).toggleClass("hidden show");
}

$(function(){
    var $write = $('#word');

    $('#key').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        character = $this.html();
        $write.html($write.html() + character);
     });
});
```

However, I must be doing something very wrong because the above code doesn't seem to do anything. Could someone please help me fix it?

**Update**: As advised by sandeep s in his answer below, I removed the `key` ID from the buttons and added a new class `spl-key` instead. The HTML now looks like this:

```
<div class="input-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <input id="word" type="textbox" placeholder="Enter your word here..." class="form-control input-lg">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="toggler('virtualkeypad');"><span class="fa fa-keyboard-o fa-2x lookup-icon"></span></a>
    <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button" id="lookup">Lookup</button></span>
</div>

<div id="virtualkeypad" class="col-md-offset-4 hidden">
    <button class="spl-key btn btn-lg special-char-btn first-btn" type="button">á</button>
    <button class="spl-key btn btn-lg special-char-btn" type="button">é</button>
    <button class="spl-key btn btn-lg special-char-btn" type="button">í</button>
    <button class="spl-key btn btn-lg special-char-btn" type="button">ó</button>
    <button class="spl-key btn btn-lg special-char-btn" type="button">ú</button>
    <button class="spl-key btn btn-lg special-char-btn" type="button">ü</button>
    <button class="spl-key btn btn-lg special-char-btn last-btn" type="button">ñ</button>
</div>
```

And I also changed the script as advised to:

```
function toggler(divId) {
    $("#" + divId).toggleClass("hidden show");
}
$(function(){
    $('.spl-key').click(function(e){
        $(e.target).toggleClass("hidden");
        character = $(e.target).text();
        $('#word').val(character);
     });
});
```

The problem, however, persists and button clicks are still unresponsive as before.

Comment: Very wrong indeed! You can't register multiple click events on the `id` field,  use a common class like `btn-lg` instead

Comment: To add text to input box you don't use `html()` but `val()`

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you want? http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/L88qpghn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your implementation:

```
$(function(){
    $('.btn-lg').click(function(e){
        $(e.target).toggleClass("hidden");
        character = $(e.target).text();
        $('#word').val(character);
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I corrected the code and updated my question. The problem still seems to persist. Please refer to the update on the question above.

Comment: This is the strangest thing I've ever come across! It works on your fiddle and yet refuses to on my site! :(

Comment: Make sure you have included jQuery in that case :)

Comment: Of course I have. I have a ton of other jQuery code snippets on my site, all of which have been working just fine. Except this one. sigh...

Comment: In that case `console.log` is your new best friend :P

Comment: I just added an `alert("test");` right after `$('#word').val(character);`, just to see if it gives a clue. And guess what, the alert refuses to show. It seems, the code isn't even registering the click event. Damn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96462/discussion-between-sandeep-s-and-thelearner).

Comment: OP wanted it to work with bootstrap. This version does not check it out http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/eekfwgz2/3/ . Here is a bootstrap friendly version http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/L88qpghn/